# How can I rename my project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a lot of code that I've written, and finally have come up with the correct branding. How can I rename my project and app in XCode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode, use the menu item "Project->Rename..."

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Name in Targets and Build n Go